# RAILS: How to get has_many associations of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

how I can get the has_many associations of a model?

For example if I have this class:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many B
  has_many C
end
```

I would a method like this:

```
A.get_has_many
```

that return

```
[B,C]
```

Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should be using ActiveRecord [reflections](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html).

Then you can type something like this:

```
A.reflect_on_all_associations.map { |assoc| assoc.name}
```

which will return your array

```
[:B, :C]
```

Comment: To get only `has_many` associations, it is possible to pass a parameter: `A.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map(&:name) #=> [:B, :C]`

Comment: is there a way to reflect (i.e. traverse) on an *instance* variable, where the associations have been eagerly loaded?

Answer (score 3):

For Example you could try :

```
aux=Array.new
Page.reflections.each { |key, value| aux << key if value.instance_of?(ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection) }
```

Hi Pioz , Have a Nice Day!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solutions:

```
def self.get_macros(macro)
  res = Array.new
  self.reflections.each do |k,v|
    res << k if v.macro == macro.to_sym
  end
  return res
end
```