# How find all the associations of an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This question [RAILS: How to get has_many associations of a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880591/rails-how-to-get-has-many-associations-of-a-model) tells how to find all the associations of a Class. I want to do this for an instance of the class.  In particular I have a User model, and when I setup a User instance, it has a number of associations e.g. user.profile, user.plans etc. I want to check all the associations have been successfully set up for a particular user instance. How do you do this?

Comment: Please check my answer bellow and see if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link you provided you should be able to accomplish what you want by doing this:

```
User.reflect_on_all_associations.map { |assoc| assoc.name }.each do |assoc|
  association_object = user.send assoc
  #note this is the user instance not the class.
  # do whatever you want with association_object. check if nil?
end
```

What the code does, it to iterate through the list of association name keys returned the link you provided and then use it to call the "method" (meaning the association) by using `send`.

Hope that helps